# Objective-C: How can I pass string to a .xib file and display a MapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a .xib file where the user can enter a location name of a place in a UITextField and click search. Then another .xib file will load where the user will see a MapView object with the location on the map.

I made a custom init method where I pass the string as follows when the user clicks the button:

```
AddLocViewController *locView = [[AddLocViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil customLoc:textLoc.text];
[self presentModalViewController:locView animated:YES];
```

In the new ViewController class called AddLocViewController.m the init method and viewDidLoad is as following:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil customLoc:(NSString*)_loc
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        stringLoc1 = _loc;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    [self showAddress];
}
```

Here [self showAddress] calls a method to display the contents on the mapView object, The showAddress method works perfectly if I have a UITextField taking input and clicking a button to set the value to a NSString object stringLoc and using that in showAddress method:

```
- (void) showAddress
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta=0.01f;
span.longitudeDelta=0.01f;

    stringLoc1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringLoc1]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

double aLatitude = 0.0;
double aLongitude = 0.0;

if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    aLatitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    aLongitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else {
    [addressField setText: @"Address Location error"];
    return;
}

[addressField resignFirstResponder];

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = {latitude: aLatitude, longitude:aLongitude};

region.span=span;
region.center.latitude = aLatitude;
    region.center.longitude = aLongitude;

    if(addAnnotation != nil) {
    [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    //[addAnnotation release];
    addAnnotation = nil;
}

    addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    [mapView addAnnotation: addAnnotation];

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
}
```

Please help me pass parameter here to this class and use the showAddress method appropriately because it only now shows the proper location when a location is searched from within the class and does not show the proper location when instantiated.

Comment: Xib files don't "do" things. Nib files with xib extensions are just a description of the layout and parameters of a view with its subviews. On the contrary. Your locView is initialised without any nib file at all.  You did not creat an init "file" but you have overwritten the inti... method. Although this sounds like fingerpointing, exact speach helps avoiding musunderstandings which is just helpful for all of us.

Comment: Sorry I meant init method my bad, will edit it.

Comment: Did you debug and find out what the initial value of the text address is? What value does textLoc.text have and therefore _loc?

Comment: Oh yes I debugged it, it shows the string fine so nothing with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you overwrite stringLoc1 with the content of the address field:
It is overwritten regardless of its initial value. If the textField is empty then it is overwirtten with an empty string.

```
stringLoc1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                       [addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am not sure what the best solution is in the context of your remaining code. But this should work:

```
NSString *currentLoc;

if (addressField.text && ([addressField.text length] == 0)) {
  currentLoc = addressFiled.text;
  stringLoc1 = addressField.text; // this line will set the current value as default value for the next call of the method; unless a new init call comes in between.
}
else
  currentLoc = stringLoc1; 


    currentLoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", 
                           [currentLoc  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentLoc ]];
```

I am sure there are smarter ways of doing that. But this should work with minimal changes to the view lines of code that you shared with us.

Comment: Its a good solution, I have just tried this but its still not working. Can you give me any pointers to where I might be going wrong? Like if I should check viewDidLoad method or not? etc

Comment: Also I just tried to use the method: 
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

Here I tried to call the showAddress method, but unfortunately same result.

Comment: viewWillAppear shoud be fine. As it is about some initial value only viewDidLoad should be ok too. And of course on any response to the button pressed when the user changes the value itself. What exactly does not work this time? What do you observe and which values do stringLoc1 and addressField.text have?

Comment: Oh yes addressField is returning null pointer in this case. Try to suggest why it is null and trying to fix it and I will ask for further help here later if that's okay.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem btw, because addressField.text is not supposed to have any value to begin because we just arrived to this class. I debugged and the names of the city are stored correctly in currentLoc and stringLoc1. So I wonder why it doesn't find it on the map.